# Repository setup for composite build

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gradle

I am working on a new project where our team has decided to use the **composite build with Gradle**. We are having a discussion about how we should set up our repository. Should we use **single repository containing all the projects**? Or should we use **separate repositories for different projects**? Which one is better practice and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both, with a git parent repo which would reference fixed SHA1 of other projects repos through **[git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

That would be consistent with what a Gradle composite build allows you to do:

> Composite builds allow you to:
>
> - combine builds that are usually developed independently, for instance when trying out a bug fix in a library that your application uses
> - decompose a large multi-project build into smaller, more isolated chunks that can be worked in independently or together as needed